# How to return an AJAX callback in IE?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I can't access the data retrieved from an AJAX request on IE11.
I am sending an AJAX request using Jquery:

In Chrome an FF i have a **responseText** field that i can easily access in the response object.

```
var ExternalApiService = (function(){
    var getTimeGMT = function(){
        return $.get("{api_path}.php",function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            return jqXHR.responseText;
        });
    };
    return{
        getTimeGMT: getTimeGMT
    }
})();
```

Then, when i call

```
ExternalApiService.getTimeGMT()
```

On Chrome and FF the object that i get in response has a **responseText** field that i can easily access.
In IE11 i don't have that field.

Yet, in the IE *developer tools*, on *Network*, inside the API call, if i click on the right side on *Body* => *Response body*, i can see that i have the text that i need. 
The API call worked, i just can't access the response body.

How do i access that data?

Comment: It's hard to imagine this code to work in any browser. Where are you returning the result of the callback function to?? And where and when are you checking `responseText`?

Comment: @Teemu means, what do you think the `return data;` statement is doing / does and what are you basing your "it's not working" on?

Comment: "*There has to be a way to access the data i[sic] got from the AJAX*" - yes, it's right there in `, function(data) {`

Comment: This is an asynchronicity issue. Quite how this works in any browser I don't know. To solve the problem you need to use the callback properly, as the duplicate I've marked shows you.

Comment: i have edited the original post

Comment: @Ori Given your update, the duplicate question is correct. You're trying to use an asynchronous function in a synchronous manner. See the stuff about `Promise` on https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), `responseText` is a parameter of the `jqXHR` object passed as the *third* parameter to your success function, not a parameter of `data`. That said, the response data is all in `data` - there's rarely a reason to go to the raw `jqXHR.responseText` value, as you already have it.

```
$.get('https://{api_path}.php',function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
     console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
     return data;
});
```

If you're making cross-domain requests without the correct CORS headers, it may not be available.

Comment: Is there any explanation for "_Obviously it works well in Chrome and FF_"?

Comment: @Teemu If it's working in those browsers, OP didn't show the actual code they're using. CORS implementations vary between browsers in my experience, and the `https://` in OP's code is further indication it might be a cross-domain request. I'm also curious if OP looked in their error console at all.